# Facebook graph-api and js-sdk issue with internet explorer 9-11

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having some issue in making social feeds work under ie9.
in this page http://www.axo.com/us/news/ there are the standard Facebook and twitter feeds widget and in ie9 are both not working.

At this other page: http://www.axo.com/us/fbfeed I'm developing a custom Facebook feed following this tutorial http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/custom-facebook-wall-jquery-graph and I get a white page under ie9

this jQuery plugin use the direct call to 'https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/posts/?access_token=XXXXXXX&callback=?&date_format=U&limit=15

I've read some post that sudgest to use the javascript SDK instead of calling graph.facebook.com. I've made a try

```
jQuery.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: 'xxxxxx',
    });     
    var pageAccessToken = 'xxxxxx';
    FB.api('/axoracing/feed', {
      access_token : pageAccessToken
    }, function(response) {
        alert("FB.api response")
    });    
});
```

but under ie9 the alert doesn't show... so I imagine the call to /axoracing/feed is not getting an answer.

even more strange: if I try to console.log() something it doesn't work in any browser (firefox, safari, chrome, ie, ...). It is really odd and it will be a mess to use the responded object if I can't log it!

I'll really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Daniele

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

For debug purpose I made a test page that call the graph api, the sdk api and the Instagram api. Instagram and graph.facebook calls work in the same way so I inserted the instagram call to check if the issue is in the capability of IE to understand the responded json (I've read this in some answare here in stackoverflow) or if it is an issue only related to facebook.

http://www.axo.com/prova.html

If I look at this page with chorme, firefox, safari and even ie7 it works fine. If I load the page with ie9 or ie11 I get only the instagram feed... no response at all from facebook!
I haven't tested ie8 or ie10 yet.

Do you have any idea? I can't believe it is a facebook incompatibility with ie... I'm sure I'm making something in the wrong way, but what?

Thank for the help

Daniele